# How to install and configure HP LTO-5 External Tape Drive to RHEL Server

Tags: rhel, devices, tape

we just bought HP LTO-5 Ultrium 3000 SAS External Tape Drive with PCIe 3.0 SAS Host Bus Adapter to be installed on HP DL380p G9 RHEL Server for connectivity.

if we install the PCIe on the server and connect Tape drive to it, How do i access the tape drive on the server for backup.
Notice, server runlevel is 3. meaning that it is purely CLI.

Answer (score 2):

The tape drive should appear as device nodes `/dev/st0` and `/dev/nst0`. If it doesn’t, try loading the `st` kernel module. This is assuming that the HBA and drive are detected — `lsscsi` will tell you whether that’s the case.